# $\int f = \int g$ and $f\le g$ $\implies f=g$ a.e.

Tags: integration, proof-verification

Given two arbitary Lebesgue integrable functions we have,

$\int f dx= \int g dx$ and  $f\le g \implies f=g$ a.e.

Proof

$\int g dx=\int f dx \implies \int g dx-\int f dx=0 \implies \int( g-f) dx=0$

since $g-f\ge 0$ we know $f=g$ by property of the integral.

This proof looks soild to me but I cant really convice myself considering the "area under the curve"

Comment: This "property of the integral" isn't trivial for this problem, I think.

Comment: Such exercise would depend on what theorems/propositions are allowed to use.

Comment: Well I used this "fact" as a part of some other proof and when I tought about it I got confused regarding the "area under the curve"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need this lemma to complete your proof:

> If $h\ge 0$ is Lebesgue measurable, then 
>   $$\int h=0\implies h=0\,\text{a.e.}$$

Proof: suppose there exists $A$ with $m(A)>0$ and $h|_A>0$, then 
$$A=\cup_n (A\cap h^{-1}((\frac1n,\infty]))$$
Since 
$$m(A)=\lim_{n\to\infty}m(A\cap h^{-1}((\frac1n,\infty]))>0$$
There exists some $k$ such that 
$$m(A\cap h^{-1}((\frac1k,\infty]))>0$$
Let $B_k:=A\cap h^{-1}((\frac1k,\infty])$, then 
$$\int h\ge\int_{B_k}h\ge\int_{B_k}\frac1k>0$$